# Laravel Eloquent add 'where' clause in the query by condition

Tags: laravel

I want to add a condition first before adding another `where` query it but seems that laravel won't allow. I want something like the following.

```
function index()
{
    $role = Auth::user()->role; //SEE_ALL, SEE_DEPT_A, SEE_DEPT_B

    $q = Input::get('q');
    if ($q != "") {
        $user = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orderBy('name');

        if ($role == "SEE_DEPT_A") {
            $user->where('user_department', "A");
        }

        $user->paginate(10)->appends('q', $q);
    }

    return view('users.index')->with('data', ['users' => $user, 'q' => $q]);
}
```

Comment: Laravel does allows it, but you are trying to use a variable out of scope. Notice the `$user` that you are passing to the view where it is initialized? It is within the if condition. You should initialize it out of it in order to use it within the method scope.

Comment: use `orderBy` at last

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the `when()` function :

```php
$user = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orderBy('name')

        ->when($role == "SEE_DEPT_A", function($query){
             return $query->where('user_department', "A");
        })->paginate(10)->appends('q', $q);
```

Comment: This is much cleaner and does not break chaning the clauses.

Comment: is it really `$query` inside the function()? Becuase it seems that the `$query->where` part did not take effect since all users are still displayed.

Comment: add return like this: `return $query->where('user_department', "A");` in when clause.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the statement where you used `where` clause:

```
 if ($role == "SEE_DEPT_A") {
        $user = $user->where('user_department', "A");
 }
```

And if the `if` statement does not run (in case of `false`), it will throw an error about `$user` being undefined

Answer (score -2):

You can insert multi conditions like this:

```
$user_model = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                    ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                    ->orderBy('name');
if ($role == "SEE_DEPT_A") {
   $user_model = $user_model->where('user_department', "A");
}
...
//other if statements
...
$users = $user_model->paginate(10)->appends('q', $q);
```

Comment: This won't work because you are not assigning the result of `$user_model->where('user_department', "A");` call to `$user_model`. It is not mutating the original variable, it returns a generated object.